# delete shared folder connection on windows

Tags: windows

We have an extern computer in our office and sometimes we need to connect it to some shared folders in our network. but afterwards we want to delete its connection. Right now we restart the machine, but I want to find out, if there is a more practical solution.

[My shared folder which I want to connect and remove afterwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO23d.png)

after some research I found out that ***net use*** does things like remove remote drives with the command

```
net use X: \delete
```

But for a shared folder I do not have a drive letter. 
Can I use ***net use*** to detach the connection to a shared folder, so that I have to **add in the username and password again** when I want to reconnect?

Or is there a different approach than ***net use***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `net use \\Computer\Sharename /delete`. You'll have to remove all shares to a single computer/server in order to log on again (`net use /user:...`). You can also use `net use * /delete` to disconnect *all* shares from a client.

Comment: Thank you very much. in my troubleshooting phase I wrote \delete instead of /delete. I assume, that I can write \\Computer\* /delete.

Comment: OK, unfortunately, " \\Computer\* /delete " is not possible

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use net use to detach the connection to a shared folder, so that
>   I have to add in the username and password again when I want to
>   reconnect?

Yes. As Zac67 stated in his comment, you can run **net use \Computer\Sharename /delete** or **net use * /delete** to delete connections to one or all shared folders.

Comment: Thank you too. Good that the /delete command removes every login credentials. That's exactly what I need

Comment: To be exact, `net use /delete` removes the login _session_. If you've stored login credentials in your user profile, these are not removed (but can be overridden by `net use /user:...`.